# Seeking IBM Watson credentials fix

Tags: api, curl, api-key, visual-recognition

I am following instructions from a github page documentation. And I am expected to provide in my API key, which I believe was auto-generated when I first signed up for IBM Watson - Visual Recognition.

`curl -X POST -u "apikey:{INSERT-YOUR-IAM-APIKEY-HERE}"`

Actually, I am posting a few zip files into IBM-Watson visual recognition and when I just do that I get following error -

`413 Request Entity Too Large`

As per the github doc, I am expected to be given a classifier ID. But I get request too large error.

So I did the obvious and tried to post one zip file in my curl command that's when I learnt I don't have my credentials set properly.. can you please help?

`{"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}` , I get this error when I try posting one zip file instead of posting a few, as said before.

Answer (score 0):

Your API key you can get from your service on the credentials page.

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

This can happen for a couple of reasons. The obvious one is you may have exceeded the limits of the file/zip size per call. Those limits can be found here.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/visual-recognition/customizing.html#size-limitations

The other reason is a known issue which is detailed in the release notes. That is the system is working on current images and it can take longer than 90 seconds. Although you get an error it should complete fine.

To stop the error in this instance is to send one set of files to train, then wait for the status to be ready from the service before sending more files. It is recommended not to check the status less then 1 time a second. Also do not try to train in parallel.

Comment: I tried just that, sent just one zip file, and when I do that, I get
 
* Could not resolve host: name=*****; Unknown error
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: name=******; Unknown error
Connected to gateway.watsonplatform.net (XXX.XX.XXX.XXX) port XXX (#1)
....
 HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< X-Note: Gateway Ack
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
< Content-Type: application/json
....
{"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}

When I try posting multiple zip file together it complains request 2 large when just 1 zip file it says unauthorized

Comment: That’s a different issue.